# 2-D barcode detection and image spliting

Tags: java, image-processing, zxing, barcode-scanner

I am working on 2d-barcode reader java ZXing library. Is it possible to identify 2d-barcode from an image which has multiple barcodes? I have to first split the detected 2d-barcodes into matrix form and then decode that. For example we have an image which has 16 different barcodes like 4*4 matrix and the desired output from that image will be:

```
        ROW      Column       Barcode output

(1,1)    1          1           784AS877
(1,2)    1          2           74AS5774
..
..
..
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. You can always tell the normal `Reader` to just look at one region of the image by using the crop parameters in `LuminanceSource`. If you know where the boxes are, that's the best thing -- loop over the areas to scan and examine them one at a time.

But you will also find support for automatically trying to find several barcode in an image in the `com.google.zxing.multi` package. Use the specialized `Reader` wrappers there to try to find them automatically. It makes some assumptions about where the barcodes are that may not let it work in this grid case, but you could try.

Comment: Thanks Sean, I'm trying automatically to find several barcode, can you please share any working example here?